# reactjs waypoint import issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jquery-waypoints

I am trying to incorporate the jquery waypoints module. I am experiencing ALL of these issues in every attempt to use the module in reactjs.-- in this case I get an each of undefined - but I have tried to even use a local version of the lib and add to the top of the file

window.jQuery = window.$ = require("jquery");

```
http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/guides/getting-started/
http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/api/waypoint/
http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/shortcuts/inview/
```

[waypoint Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'each' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46105786/waypoint-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-each-of-undefined)

[Waypoint npm - Error: Can't resolve 'waypoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43282985/waypoint-npm-error-cant-resolve-waypoint)

```
in some instances - it errors -- "TypeError:`_libs_jquery_waypoints_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3___default.a is not a constructor"`

https://github.com/imakewebthings/waypoints/issues/559
```

importing like this

```
import Waypoint from './libs/jquery.waypoints.js';
```

code

```
var ele
new Waypoint({
element: ele = $('.threesixty')[0],
handler: function(direction) {
if (direction == 'down') {
  $(ele).addClass('muestra')
} else {
  $(ele).removeClass('muestra')
}
  console.log(direction);
}
});
```

Comment: is there a vanilla way of doing this - with regular javascript --

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this imported by the following.
http://jsfiddle.net/Lfhepta3/7/

Import from a lib file.

```
import waypoint from './libs/jquery.waypoints.js';
```

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.js

At the top of the file - I've added the following line

```
window.jQuery = window.$ = require("jquery");
```

--
then the usage I've used is this.

```
              var elem = "vision0";
              var $el = $('.'+elem);

              $el.waypoint(function(direction) {
                if (direction == 'down') {
                  $el.addClass("js-"+elem+"-animate");
                } else {
                  $el.removeClass("js-"+elem+"-animate");
                }
              }, {
                offset: '50%'
              });
```

the div is like this

```
      <img className="vision0" src={require(`img/${this.props.data.image}`)} width="900" />
```